# JavaScript Array forEach function not working?

Tags: javascript

I tried to do some changes in the W33 school's javascript code to learn about the difference
between forEach and map, is there anyone can please tell me why the output of this code is still:

45,4,9,16,25

instead of

90,8,18,32,50

Isn't it forEach means call a function to every element in this array? I know I should not use return because the forEach does not return valid result.

```js
const numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

numbers.forEach(myFunction);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers;

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  value * 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Array.forEach()</h2>
  <p>Calls a function once for each array element.</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't modify the array, it just calls the function with each array element as the argument. Also, the function doesn't return anything. It calculates `value * 2` but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: for each only executes the function for every element in the array, it doesn't create a  new array

Comment: use map instead  const newNumbers = numbers.map(myFunction) and return value *2

Comment: or push elements in a new array from the myFunction

Comment: But if you really want to modify the array, you can use this, `numbers.forEach((number, index) => (numbers[index] = number * 2));`

Comment: `forEach` _can_ modify the array but you need to assign the new value back to the element at the index. `numbers[index] = value * 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `value * 2` performs a calculation, but it doesn't do anything with the result of that calculation. You could change the line to `value = value * 2` and that would assign the result of the calculation to the `value` variable. However, that still wouldn't change the values in the array, because the `value` variable is restricted to the scope of the function.

This is because when you transfer a number to another variable, you are only transferring the *value*, not the reference. i.e.

```js
let a = 1;
let b = a;
a = 2; // a is 2, b is 1
```

This is different to arrays and objects, where the reference is transferred:

```js
let a = [1];
let b = a;
a[0] = 2; // a[0] is 2, b[0] is 2
```

So a way to fix your code might be to manipulate the array instead, i.e.

```js
const numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  array[index] = value * 2;
}

// numbers is [90,8,18,32,50]
```

This works. However, I would recommend the simplicity of `map` instead of `forEach`. `Array#map` uses the return value of each function call to replace each item in the array.

```js
const numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
const doubles = numbers.map(myFunction);

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  return value * 2;
}

// numbers is [45,4,9,16,25]
// doubles is [90,8,18,32,50]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `myFunction` basically does nothing, it doubles the current value and does nothing with it. In your case, you need to mutate the array. But it's not a good idea to mutate the array which you're traversing.

To achieve your goal, I recommend creating a new array using the `map` function.

```js
const numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

const doubledNumbers = numbers.map(val => val * 2); // [90, 8, 18, 32, 50]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = doubledNumbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not re-setting the value of numbers with the multiplied value.

You need to set it according to `numbers[index]` inside the map function.

```js
const numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

numbers.forEach(myFunction);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers;

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  numbers[index] = value * 2;
}
```